# Remote repository in gitk

Tags: git

I am trying to learn Git at a very basic level from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html).

I was able to create a local repository for my project, add files and commit to it, clone the repository to a remote repository (using `--bare`), and then push the changes of my project to the remote repository. So far, so good.

Now when I do `gitk --all`, I can correctly see my local git history, but it does not show the remote repository. This is [the page I'm using to understand gitk](http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/09/03/use-gitk-to-understand-git/).

When I cloned the remote repository to a new Git repository in another directory, all my files were available. So the remote repository seems to be working fine.

Is the remote repository supposed to be seen in gitk? What am I not understanding? How can I get a visual for the remote repository?

Comment: I'd recommend that you go through http://progit.org/book/ to study the system. I expect that the rewards will be greater than the method you're current using to study git.

Comment: I think you are looking for `git branch -r`, which shows you all the remote branches.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will read the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `git fetch` to update the local "view" of the remote repository, then run `gitk --all` again. That should result in labels for the remote refs showing up as well.

(Note that this assumes that you've added the remote repository as a named remote in your local repository. If not, you won't be able to use gitk to review remote pointers.)

Comment: Yes I've added the remote repository. After the 'fetch' it does show the remote this way, and now I think I understand the concept a little better as well. Thankyou.